# How to perform ActiveRecord's query current_user.articles equivalent with Ecto?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

In Rails AR is possible to run queries like this:

```
current_user.articles # fetch all articles from current_user
SELECT * from articles where user_id = <user_id>;
```

There's an equivalent way to do this with Ecto?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
articles = Repo.all(from a in assoc(current_user, :articles))
```

or preload the articles into the user

```
current_user = Repo.preload(current_user, [:articles])
current_user.articles
```